# Getting a ear to function after adding arquillian testing

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

I have a perfectly functionning application that I then package to an ear to run on a jboss application server. This working I started to implement testing.
Now my tests work with the profile however my ear now refuses to deploy with a strange error coming in.

Here is my pom.xml with the different profiles:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- JBoss, Home of Professional Open Source Copyright 2013, Red Hat, Inc. 
    and/or its affiliates, and individual contributors by the @authors tag. See 
    the copyright.txt in the distribution for a full listing of individual contributors. 
    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not 
    use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy 
    of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Unless required 
    by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the 
    License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS 
    OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific 
    language governing permissions and limitations under the License. -->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>ithink</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.fluxon.iflux</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>ithink-ejb</artifactId>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>

    <name>ithink: EJB Module</name>

    <url>http://wildfly.org</url>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- Declare the APIs we depend on and need for compilation. All of them 
            are provided by JBoss WildFly -->

        <!-- Import the EJB API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
            JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
            JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the JPA API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
            JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSR-303 (Bean Validation) Implementation -->
        <!-- Provides portable constraints such as @Email -->
        <!-- Hibernate Validator is shipped in JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- To initialize collections -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- To deal with tests -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.ejb.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Tell Maven we are using EJB 3.1 -->
                    <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- The default profile skips all tests, though you can tune it to run 
                just unit tests based on a custom pattern -->
            <!-- Seperate profiles are provided for running all tests, including Arquillian 
                tests that execute in the specified container -->
            <id>default</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.surefire.plugin}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>arquillian-jbossas-managed</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                    <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-web-6.0</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0.Final</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>xalan</groupId>
                            <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <testResources>
                    <testResource>
                        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                    </testResource>
                    <testResource>
                        <directory>src/test/resources-jbossas-managed</directory>
                    </testResource>
                </testResources>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>arquillian-glassfish-embedded</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.CR3</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
                    <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-web</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <testResources>
                    <testResource>
                        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                    </testResource>
                    <testResource>
                        <directory>src/test/resources-glassfish-embedded</directory>
                    </testResource>
                </testResources>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.12</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <systemPropertyVariables>
                                <java.util.logging.config.file>
                                    ${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/logging.properties
                                </java.util.logging.config.file>
                                <derby.stream.error.file>
                                    ${project.build.directory}/derby.log
                                </derby.stream.error.file>
                            </systemPropertyVariables>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

    </profiles>

</project>
```

and here is my error stack when I launch my local server:

```
23:33:05,203 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "ithink-ear.ear")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"ithink-ear.ear\".WeldStartService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"ithink-ear.ear\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to acquire SerialContextProvider for SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.ldap.version=3, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Orb initialization erorr]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.initialize(CDIExtension.java:196)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.beforeBeanDiscovery(CDIExtension.java:297)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:88)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SpecialParamPlusBeanManagerStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:144)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:306)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:121)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:284)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:262)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:271)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:260)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:154)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:148)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:54)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:42)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.fire(BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.java:45)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.startInitialization(WeldStartup.java:368)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startInitialization(WeldBootstrap.java:76)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:92)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to acquire SerialContextProvider for SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.ldap.version=3, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Orb initialization erorr]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContext.java:351)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.createSubcontext(SerialContext.java:937)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.createSubcontext(InitialContext.java:489)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.createSubcontext(InitialContext.java:489)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.createSubcontext(InitialContext.java:489)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension$1.stepInto(CDIExtension.java:280)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.diveIntoJNDIContext(CDIExtension.java:267)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.createJerseyConfigJNDIContext(CDIExtension.java:273)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.initialize(CDIExtension.java:192)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Orb initialization erorr
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getORB(GlassFishORBHelper.java:180)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getORB(SerialContext.java:364)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProviderCacheKey(SerialContext.java:371)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getRemoteProvider(SerialContext.java:401)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContext.java:346)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getORB(GlassFishORBHelper.java:152)
    ... 38 more
"}}
```

I have tried activating and deactivating the profile but as soon as I add the testing profile I fall back to this state.

Thank you a lot for any help,

My arquillian.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
    http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">
<container qualifier="glassfish-embedded" default="true">
    <configuration>
        <property name="resourcesXml">
            src/test/resources-glassfish-embedded/glassfish-resources.xml
        </property>
    </configuration>
</container>
```

Comment: It sounds a bit odd to me that you are trying to run jersey instead of relying what is the default JAX-RS implemenation in Wildfly - RESTEasy. That might be a problem for my taste. Can you deploy this application on its own in Wildfly without any issues?

Comment: Yes there are no problems to deploy the application, it only messes up when I add the arquillian-glassfish-embedded and it continues even when I deactivate it and update maven dependencies.

Comment: Concerning jersey actually I am not quite sure from where it comes from and I can't seem to find it anywhere in my project

Comment: How does your `arquillian.xml` look like?